# Span tag is not working properly in MVC View razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to perform the mathematical operations in ASP.NET MVC. In below code, everything is working fine. But, In span tag variable 'n' is not incrementing after using "switch" condition. It is taking "0" only. Please check. here is no code in controller, only "return View()" statement is available.

View Code:

```html
<h2>Get Value</h2>
<hr />

<form action="/Assignment03/Count" method="post">
    Enter First Name :<input type="text" id="firstNumber" name="firstNumber" /><br />
    Enter Second Number : <input type="text" id="secondNumber" name="secondNumber" /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="+" id="Add" name="getValue"/>&nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="submit" value="-" id="Sub" name="getValue"/>&nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="submit" value="*" id="Mul" name="getValue"/>&nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="submit" value="/" id="Div" name="getValue"/>&nbsp; &nbsp;
</form>

@{
  if(IsPost == true)
  {
      if(Request["firstNumber"] != string.Empty && Request["secondNumber"] != string.Empty)
      {
          int n1 = int.Parse(Request["firstNumber"]);
          int n2 = int.Parse(Request["secondNumber"]);
          int n=0;

          string value = Request["getValue"];

          switch (value)
          {
              case "Add":
                  n = n1 + n2;
                  break;
              case "Sub":
                  n = n1 - n2;
                  break;
              case "Mul":
                  n = n1 * n2;
                  break;
              case "Div":
                  n = n1 / n2;
                  break;
          }
        <span>@n</span>                           
      }
      else
      {
          <span>Please Enter Any number</span>
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Debug your code. What are the values of `n1` and `n2` and `value`? But why are you doing a POST when you could simply do this calculation on the client side using javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, problem is in `string value = Request["getValue"];` and swith-case statements.
You set valus in your input like `+` and `-`... but in case you compare it with `Add` and `Sub`. Try to replace it like this:

```
      switch (value)
      {
          case "+":
              n = n1 + n2;
              break;
          case "-":
              n = n1 - n2;
              break;
          case "*":
              n = n1 * n2;
              break;
          case "/":
              n = n1 / n2;
              break;
      }
```

Comment: Yes I changed the values as Add, Sub, Mul, and Div. Now Everything is working properly. Thanks a lot.. But One thing i want to ask you is, Sometime it may be our requirement to add +, -,* , / symbols, that time how we can manage. Please clarify...

Comment: So from your original post it looks like you wanted to display symbols to the user and use the Id's for your switch. Why not switch on the Id of the button that was pressed vs the value of the control.